# Seleccionar celda datagrid wpf JSON y pasar datos a otro formulario xaml

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml, jsonarray

Intente desde esta manera se visualizan los datos segun lo buscado pero a la hora de seleccionar el medicamento en el datagrid me envia error ("Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.'") los datos quedan en el array me muestra los 8 objetos de la lista que estoy seleccionado.
La idea es ya seleccionado el dato en el datagrid pasar los datos de esa celda a un nuevo formulario "CRUDMedicamento.xaml" rellenando con los datos seleccionados.

---

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var json = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.xxxx.xx/medicamentos?nombre=" + txt_nombre.Text);

        IList<Medicamento> informacion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Medicamento>>(json);

        datagrid_medicamento.ItemsSource = null;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("ID").ReadOnly = true;
        dt.Columns.Add("Nombre").ReadOnly = true;
        dt.Columns.Add("Stock").ReadOnly = true;
        dt.Columns.Add("Descripción").ReadOnly = true;
        dt.Columns.Add("Fabricante").ReadOnly = true;
        dt.Columns.Add("Tipo Medicamento").ReadOnly = true;
        dt.Columns.Add("Gramaje").ReadOnly = true;
        dt.Columns.Add("Tipo Gramaje").ReadOnly = true;


        List<Medicamento> listaMedicamentos = new List<Medicamento>();

        foreach (Medicamento obj in informacion)
        {
            listaMedicamentos.Add(obj);

            dt.Rows.Add(obj.id_medicamento.ToString(), obj.nombre.ToString(), obj.stock.ToString(),
                            obj.descripcion.ToString(), obj.fabricante.ToString(), obj.tipo_medicamento_texto.ToString(),
                            obj.gramaje.ToString(), obj.tipo_gramaje_texto.ToString());
        }

        datagrid_medicamento.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

---

```
private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        CrudMedicamento detalle = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CrudMedicamento>(((DataRowView)datagrid_medicamento.Items.CurrentItem).Row.ItemArray.ToString());

        NavigationWindow navWIN = new NavigationWindow();
        navWIN.Content = new CrudMedicamento();
        navWIN.Show();

    }
```

---

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,96,10,0">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="360" x:Name="datagrid_medicamento" Margin="10,0,-22,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1014" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ToggleButton  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionAccentToggleButton}" Click="ToggleButton_Click" IsChecked="True"  ToolTip="MaterialDesignActionAccentToggleButton" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: El `datagridview` que mencionas es el grid de winform, no de wpf

Comment: Cual seria el problema? no deserializa?, no se visualizan los datos en el grid? no se asigna el `ItemsSource`?  porque entiendo que el `list` que usas en el DataGrid lo asignas con el `re`, no ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no se visualizan los datos en el grid. intente de esta otra manera

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el codigo puedes ver que la variable `re` y la propiedad `list` tienen items? No se porque la clase `Medicamento` tiene propiedade privada en lugar de usar propiedades, ademas no necesitas un constructor con todos los valores si estas deserializando, no necesitas ningun constructor, solo propiedades public

Comment: @LeandroTuttini deje una respuesta mas abajo de lo que estoy haciendo

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Ahi reformule la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275787/seleccionar-celda-datagrid-wpf-json-y-pasar-a-otro-formulario

Comment: No tenes que reformular la pregunta en otra. Tenes que editar la misma y seguir trabajando sobre ella, si no se pierde todo el trabajo que por ejemplo hizo leandro para tratar de entender tu problema.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini AP viene de un entorno web y piensa que wpf se maneja como web. Su problema es no saber como funciona una app de escritorio